# Theme Design & Development For Mobile Phones

Tags: iphone, android, windows, mobile, themes

Hey looking out for theme development for various Mobile Devices & Platform:

Nokia and Sony have official Themes Creators/Preview and Manual. look for others also.

LG,HTC,Blackberry, Android,iPhones,Windows Mobile etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what question you are asking... There isn't a theme builder for iPhone.  I know some people jbreak their phones and mess with the themes by using photo shop but I'd think twice before doing so if you are developing for the iphone.

Comment: I think he needs some like this: http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Mobile_web_browsing/Web_templates/

Comment: yup agree default iPhone look and feel is much better ! for android i guess we need to mess with the OS it self ? can we have themes for windows, Java and Symbain ?